# Unable to retrieve metadata for abc.models.abcviewmodel

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have  a ViewModel

```
    public class abcViewModel
     {
        public List<tblUserTeam> UserTeam { get; set; }
     }

    public partial class tblUserTeam
    {
       public int UserId { get; set; }
       public int MatchId { get; set; }
       public int PlayerId { get; set; }
       [Display(Name = "Caption")]
       public Nullable<bool> IsCaption { get; set; }

       public virtual tblMatch tblMatch { get; set; }
       public virtual tblPlayer tblPlayer { get; set; }
       public virtual tblUser tblUser { get; set; }
    }

  public partial class tblMatch
    {
        public tblMatch()
        {
            this.tblScores = new HashSet<tblScore>();
            this.tblUserTeams = new HashSet<tblUserTeam>();
        }

        public int MatchId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> MatchDateTime { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Team1 { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Team2 { get; set; }
        public string Location { get; set; }

        public virtual tblTeam tblTeam { get; set; }
        public virtual tblTeam tblTeam1 { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<tblScore> tblScores { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<tblUserTeam> tblUserTeams { get; set; }
    }
public partial class tblPlayer
    {
        public tblPlayer()
        {
            this.tblScores = new HashSet<tblScore>();
            this.tblUserTeams = new HashSet<tblUserTeam>();
        }

        public int playerId { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Player")]
        public string PlayerName { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> TeamId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> CountryId { get; set; }
        public string StatisticsWebsite { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime dtCreated { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Price { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Speciality { get; set; }

        public virtual tblCountry tblCountry { get; set; }
        public virtual tblPlayerSpeciality tblPlayerSpeciality { get; set; }
        public virtual tblTeam tblTeam { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<tblScore> tblScores { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<tblUserTeam> tblUserTeams { get; set; }
    }
public partial class tblUser
    {
        public tblUser()
        {
            this.tblUserTeams = new HashSet<tblUserTeam>();
        }

        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> dtCreated { get; set; }
        public string TeamName { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<tblUserTeam> tblUserTeams { get; set; }
    }
```

When i try to create controller and view of the above viewmodel with scaffolding i get this error **"Unable to retrieve metadata for abc.models.abcviewmodel"**

Please guide me whats wrong in this.

Comment: I'm guessing EF is trying to lazy load all your tblMatch, tblPlayer and tblUser but is not being able to. Can you show some code from controller and view?

Comment: @Biplov13. I have added definations of Virtual properties. This should help you to understand the problem

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you don't have a data context class set in your "Add Controller" or "Add View" dialog box if you're generating from a poco.

Answer (score 0):

Just compile and build your code once and try again since it uses reflection for identifying the models.